# Relationship between sequence limit ($N \rightarrow R$) and corresponding function limit ($R \rightarrow R$)

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, education

I have the sequence ($N \rightarrow R$):

$$ n \, \left( 2^{1/n} \, - \, 1 \right) $$

If I consider the limit:

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow + \infty} {n \, \left( 2^{1/n} \, - \, 1 \right)} $$

and the limit of the function ($R \rightarrow R$):

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow + \infty} {x \, \left( 2^{1/x} \, - \, 1 \right)} $$

is there some formal mathematical reason that ensures me that the two limits are equal?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the limit exists in $\mathbb{R}$, it exists in $\mathbb{N}$ and they are equal. But the limit can exist in $\mathbb{N}$ without existing in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hello @Thorgott, can you indicate me an example that shows a limit which exists in N, but not in R please?

Comment: The limit of the sequence $(\sin(2\pi n))_n$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ is $0$ (in fact, the sequence is constant zero), but the limit of the function $x\mapsto\sin(2\pi x)$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$ does not exist.

Comment: Thank you very much @Thorgott